# java.lang.Class<....ViewModel> has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

Im implementing ViewModel with ViewModel factory and got crashes on some devices on firebase crashlytics.

the app is not crashing when I am testing on my devices.

here is part of the code related to the ViewModel:

in the activity (the factory injected with dagger 2):

```
myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, myViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

the factory:

```
public static class MyViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private final MyRepository myRepository;

    @Inject
    public MyViewModelFactory(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel.class)) {
            return (T) new MyViewModel(myRepository);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");
    }
}
```

the view model constructor:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    ...

    public MyViewModel(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    ...

}
```

the exception im getting:

```
Caused by java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<....MyViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:152)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:211)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:135)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:103)
       at .....MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:140)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

any idea what could cause the issue?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like it is not using your factory. Are you sure that this stack trace is coming from the activity line that you cite? If you put a breakpoint on that line and look at `myViewModelFactory`, is it really an instance of `MyViewModelFactory`?

Comment: Is the Factory null? If it is then `ViewModelProfider.of()` falls back to default factory (which cant handle a lack of zero arg ViewModel constructor)

Comment: unfortunately i cant put a breakpoint because in my devices (tested around 10) its not happening.. but i will look into it sounds like the factory is actually null.. thanks

Comment: If the ViewModelFactory is null, it will default to NewInstanceFactory, so it tries to use no-arg constructor. But if you provide where `VMFactory` comes from, maybe we'll know more

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the factory injected by dagger 2 in my activity:
     
    \@Inject MyViewModel.MyViewModelFactory myViewModelFactory;

Comment: That's not really saying anything because I don't know where you are calling the injection and if the crash happens in for example `onAttach` of a Fragment calling `ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()`.

Comment: `myViewModelFactory` is null

Comment: probably this is the issue, im unable to figure out why sometimes dagger inject it and sometimes not